# Is there a benefit to using a specific language with Selenium WebDriver?

Tags: java, c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

As I begin to make the leap from the Firefox **Selenium IDE** to **Selenium 2**, I'm realizing that a significant portion of tutorials, guides, books, and documentation regarding **WebDriver** is based in **Java**; **C#** seems to take a somewhat close second.

- Is there a benefit to one language (C#, Java, Python, Ruby) over the
  other?
- Does the chosen **IDE** (Visual Studio, Eclipse, etc.) of the language play a significant role in its application of Selenium 2?
- Should the language of the project being tested play a pivotal role in determining what language is chosen to run Selenium 2 in? (In other words, if the dev team is writing in C# .NET should I, the SQA dev, run WebDriver in C# too?)

Comment: This is more of a Programmers question. A good rule of thumb is Objective Questions = Stackoverflow, Subjective Questions = Programmers. I only say this as it's likely this question will be closed and I want to make sure it's moved appropriately.

Comment: @AndrewTFinnell Thank you, I appreciate that.

Comment: Imagine if you will that the Automation department is a group all of their own. They could build a system which is capable of testing many different kinds of products across many different platforms. i.e. pick a language and tool set the entry level testers can use and don't let the developers choose. Developers tend to make things complicated, where Automated testing should be simple. Testing the product doesn't have to have anything to do with the language the product was built in. Some products even use multiple languages. Look at this from a QA perspective not dev. My 2 cents.

Comment: @AndrewTFinnell Haha "Developers tend to make things complicated". Whelp, that whole heatedly probably describes my narrative to approaching this new job (SQA). I've been a developer but never a QA/tester before so Im really taking baby steps at this point; every bit of advice helps. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's break it down in 3 parts:

1. > Is there a benefit to one language (C#, Java, Python, Ruby) over the
   >   other?

The WebDriver's API is almost 1:1 for C# and Java. Most of the stuff have even the same name (like classes or methods) exceptions being language reserved words (like `Select` for C#). Regarding the support, a solution used to fix an issue with Selenium posted for Java will most likely work for C# and vice-versa.
For the others like Python and Ruby I have too little knowledge to pronounce myself, although the Python binding is pretty much used.

2. > Does the chosen IDE (Visual Studio, Eclipse, etc.) of the language
   >   play a significant role in its application of Selenium 2?

It all breaks down to your liking. For C# will most likely use Visual Studio and for Java you have IntelliJ and Eclipse, although I prefer IntelliJ over Eclipse.

3. > Should the language of the project being tested play a pivotal role in
   >   determining what language is chosen to run Selenium 2 in? (In other
   >   words, if the dev team is writing in C# .NET should I, the SQA dev,
   >   run WebDriver in C# too?)

This is not something mandatory, because in the end, Selenium doesn't really care what's behind, only cares about what the browser is rendering.

**However this is preferred**, because it will most likely make your job a lot easier. If you work in a company with Selenium (and not doing stuff on your own) you will find yourself in the position where you'll need to use something from the developers work. This can be something from classes and methods to setup the environment, start some services, doing some backend stuff to achieve something on the UI that shouldn't be tested by Selenium, etc etc to even simpler and easier stuff like using the bindings for localization for instance.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, it doesn't really matter what language you choose to write the selenium code in. Selenium is a library of commands (Written in Java, I believe) that can be accessed through many other languages. It is good practice to write all your selenium code files in the same language, but that language does not have to match the application.

Java has the advantage of being most widely used, so it is easier to find examples, but other than that they should be essentially the same.

Another factor to think about is what kind of testing framework is inherent in the language. Python has the Unittest class, Java has JUnit, etc.

I prefer python due to its simplicity, as Java/C# can have more complicated syntax, but the final answer is for you to use the language that you are most comfortable in.

[More details here](https://www.joecolantonio.com/2015/05/31/selenium-what-programming-language-you-should-learn-to-get-into-test-automation/)